# How would you add the name of a variable to a file name in Python 3.4?

Tags: file, python-3.x

Intuitively, although I know this is wrong, it would look something like this:

```
secondFileNamePart = "7"
file = open(('test+secondFileNamePart.txt'), 'w')
```

With the name of the new file being test7.
Obviously though, this does not work. Is their any way to do this, or if not a workaround? I want to create a user specified number of files, all with different names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider [reading the Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) - string concatenation is a basic topic.

```
secondFileNamePart = '7'
file = open('test'+secondFileNamePart+'.txt', 'w')
```